# np array how to create array of lists with different sizes?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-science, numpy-ndarray

I want to create an np.array with 3 elements - each is an array with different dimenstions.

The first column is `1X14`, the second column is `1X768`, and the 3rd column is `(3,244,244)`.

I tried the following code:

```
X = np.empty((self.batch_size, 1, 3))
y = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=int)


# Generate data
for i, id in enumerate(ids):
    x_features = df.iloc[id][A_COLS] 
    x_text = df.iloc[id][B_COL]
    x_data = df.iloc[id][C_COL])

    X[i,0] = x_features # x_features shape is 1X14
    X[i,1] = x_text # x_features shape is 1X768
    X[i,2] = x_data # x_features shape is (3,244,244)
```

But I got the error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (14) into shape (3)
```

How can I create this array?

Thanks

Comment: Set dtype=object for X

Comment: Why?  What's wrong with a list?

Comment: @tstanisl the error remains the same

Comment: @hpaulj The array should be fed the NN so it has to be in the form of np array

Comment: Are you sure your NN will be happy with an array containing arrays of different sizes?  Look at your `df.dtypes`.  Are those `integer` or `object`?  Given that `X` definition, `X[i,0]` can only hold 3 float numbers.  And X[i,1]` will produce an indexing error.  You need to read more `numpy` basics (as well as learn what your NN really expects).

Comment: @hpaulj Can you help here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64524078/python-cant-apply-fit-generator-to-keras-model-with-multiple-input?noredirect=1#comment114092628_64524078 As feeding this NN is the goal and I am not sure how to fit it

Comment: You have not understood what your NN requires.  Typically the `X` tensor contains batches of identically size numeric arrays.  `y` contains labels, numeric or possibly text.  You don't put features, labels and data into one tensor.

Comment: @hpaulj But notice that my NN have 3 input. So if it was `fit()` and nit `fit_generator()` I would put `net.fit([X_features, X_text, X_data], y`. I am trying to "translate" this to use `fit_generator` because of memory considerations